# combinar combobox con entrybox segun la opcion del combobox

Tags: python, combobox, tinker

hace poco realice una pregunta y quede muy satisfecho con ella pero en realidad no pense bien que era lo que deseaba,,,y por eso vuelvo a preguntar,,supongamos que tenemos

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
raiz =Tk()
raiz.title("hola")
raiz.geometry("1000x850")
raiz.config(bg ="gray")
raiz.config(bd="30")
raiz.config(relief="groove")
miframe = Frame(raiz,bg="white",width="1000", height="650")
miframe.pack(fill ="both",expand = "True")



combobox = ttk.Combobox(miframe,width="30",state="readonly")
combobox["values"]=("Color","Tamaño")
combobox.grid(row="5",column="1")
combobox1 = ttk.Combobox(miframe,width="30",state="readonly")
combobox1["values"]=("azul","amarillo","rojo")
combobox1.grid(row="6",column="1")
textolabel=Label(miframe,text="Tamaño")
textolabel.grid(row="0",column="0")
texto= Entry(miframe,width="30",state="disable")
texto.grid(row="0",column="1")
raiz.mainloop()
```

es decir dos combobox y un entry,,lo que deseo es lo sgt,,,si en el primer combobox se escoje la opcion color se mantenga descativado el entrybox, se active el segundo combobox y la respuesta a ese combobox sea mediante el  escojiendo el valor del color que se desee.ahora si en el primer combobox se escoje la opcion tamaño se descative el segundo combobox ,se active el entrybox y la caracteristica del tamaño sea escrita en ese entrybox,,,pudiendo escribir cosas como grande,,prequeño o lo que desees,,esto es en realidad lo que deseo

Comment: una ayudita con esta por favor no logro implementar eso,,gracias

Comment: Me podrían ayudar por favor..